# Display call transaction screen in a Splitter-container

Tags: abap, docking, splitter

I have a program which displays a splitter-container with two columns:

- Left side displays a control tree (this is OK)
- Right side should displays a custom TCode  (not sure how to do this bit)

On double-click of a tree node, it calls a transaction which opens a screen, but it opens in a new window.

How to open the screen in the right-side window?

Minimal reproducible example:

- Create the transaction code **ZCALL_ZPRG1** via `SE93`, so that it calls the program `ZPRG1`
- Create the program **ZPRG1** (minimalist screen):

```
REPORT zprg1.
PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
```

- Create the program **ZPRG2** (splitter and tree):

```
    REPORT zprg2.
    CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
      PUBLIC SECTION.
        METHODS:
          pbo,
          on_node_double_click FOR EVENT node_double_click OF cl_gui_simple_tree.
        DATA:
          tree     TYPE REF TO cl_gui_simple_tree,
          itab     TYPE TABLE OF mtreesnode,
          splitter TYPE REF TO cl_gui_splitter_container.
    ENDCLASS.
    CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
      METHOD pbo.
        CHECK tree IS NOT BOUND.
        CREATE OBJECT splitter
          EXPORTING
            parent  = cl_gui_container=>screen0
            rows    = 1
            columns = 2.
        itab = VALUE #(
        ( node_key = '1'
          text     = 'Double-click me' ) ).
        CREATE OBJECT tree
          EXPORTING
            parent              = splitter->get_container( row = 1 column = 1 )
            node_selection_mode = cl_gui_simple_tree=>node_sel_mode_single.
        tree->add_nodes(
              table_structure_name = 'MTREESNODE'
              node_table           = itab ).
        SET HANDLER on_node_double_click FOR tree.
        DATA events TYPE cntl_simple_events.
        CALL METHOD tree->set_registered_events
          EXPORTING
            events = VALUE #( ( eventid = tree->eventid_node_double_click ) )
          EXCEPTIONS
            OTHERS = 4.
      ENDMETHOD.
      METHOD on_node_double_click.
        CALL TRANSACTION 'ZCALL_ZPRG1'.
      ENDMETHOD.
    ENDCLASS.

    DATA: app TYPE REF TO lcl_app.

    PARAMETERS dummy.

    INITIALIZATION.
      CREATE OBJECT app.

    AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
      app->pbo( ).

    AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON EXIT-COMMAND.
      app->splitter->free( ).
```

- **Run ZPRG2**
- Double-click the tree node

Comment: I have reworded the question so that it conforms more stackoverflow principles (especially adding a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Please confirm whether it fits your question, or edit it. Thx. PS: it's important to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) i.e. which conform stackoverflow principles, I won't do it next time.

Comment: I am new to blog hence leaning how to frame question and answer. Hoping to get on speed soon. Thanks a lot Sandra for your help and patience. !! Your code really helps & working but on click of node the transaction should get open in right side panel of the same window instead of new window. Appreciate your valuable comments/suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In the SAP GUI, it is possible to mix screens of [dynpro](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_dynpros.htm) technology and [GUI controls](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abengui_control_glosry.htm) of the [SAP Control Framework](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q="SAP%20Control%20Framework"&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750) in these ways:

- Screen and [Docking Containers](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q="SAP%20Docking%20Container"&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750) ; these containers may be displayed at any of the 4 sides of the screen

  - In these containers can be placed GUI controls (including splitter containers)
- Screen containing a so-called [Custom Container](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22SAP%20Custom%20Container%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750) area in which can be placed GUI controls (including splitter containers)
- Popups can be displayed over any dynpro screen or GUI control; those popups may also contain any (other) dynpro screen or GUI control; they are completely independent from the screen below. Popups may also be displayed over popups.

It is not possible to embed a dynpro screen inside a GUI control (including containers) in any manner.

So, in your case, the only solution is to use a **docking container** on the left of your dynpro screen. But only the program which displays the dynpro screen is allowed to "add" the docking container (i.e. `CALL TRANSACTION` or `SUBMIT` cannot be used).

Consequently, `ZPRG2` must handle both your GUI control and a dynpro screen. You have two options to handle the dynpro screen:

1. Either `ZPRG2` handles it (everything is done by ZPRG2, you don't need ZPRG1)
2. Or you only define a [subscreen area](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abensubscreen_arrea_glosry.htm) inside the dynpro screen of `ZPRG2`, and you include a subscreen from `ZPRG1` which handles all the initializations and interactions of the subscreen.

The second solution is recommended because it permits the [Separation Of Concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The code below is a minimal example to demonstrate how it could work, that will allow you to debug and understand better; there are so many things to explain that I prefer to let you ask questions in the comments (or new questions); be aware that many of the algorithm, statements and tricks below are not advised, I use them just because they are much shorter. You will end up with a much more complex program than this one.

- Program **ZPRG1** (right side, show/hide UI elements to react to double click at left side):

```
REPORT zprg1.
DATA display TYPE abap_bool VALUE abap_false.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 0100 AS SUBSCREEN.
PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 0100.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF display = abap_false.
    LOOP AT SCREEN.
      screen-active = '0'.
      MODIFY SCREEN.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.

FORM toggle_display.
  IF display = abap_false.
    display = abap_true.
  ELSE.
    display = abap_false.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

- Program **ZPRG2** (left side tree + handling of subscreen area at the right to include ZPRG1 screen):

```
REPORT zprg2.
DATA okcode TYPE syucomm. " global variable for dynpro 0200 "OKCODE" element

CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      pbo,
      pai,
      on_node_double_click FOR EVENT node_double_click OF cl_gui_simple_tree.
    DATA:
      tree    TYPE REF TO cl_gui_simple_tree,
      itab    TYPE TABLE OF mtreesnode,
      docking TYPE REF TO cl_gui_docking_container.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD pbo.
    SET PF-STATUS space. " <=== trick to activate buttons in the system toolbar
    CHECK tree IS NOT BOUND.
    CREATE OBJECT docking
      EXPORTING
        repid     = sy-repid
        dynnr     = sy-dynnr
        side      = docking->dock_at_left
        extension = 400    " pixels
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS    = 6.
    itab = VALUE #(
        ( node_key = '1'
          text     = 'Double-click me' ) ).
    CREATE OBJECT tree
      EXPORTING
        parent              = docking
        node_selection_mode = cl_gui_simple_tree=>node_sel_mode_single.
    tree->add_nodes(
          table_structure_name = 'MTREESNODE'
          node_table           = itab ).
    SET HANDLER on_node_double_click FOR tree.
    DATA events TYPE cntl_simple_events.
    CALL METHOD tree->set_registered_events
      EXPORTING
        events = VALUE #( ( eventid = tree->eventid_node_double_click
                            appl_event = 'X' ) ) " <=== to trigger the PAI
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS = 4.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD on_node_double_click.
    PERFORM toggle_display IN PROGRAM zprg1.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD pai.
    CASE okcode.
      WHEN 'BACK' OR 'RW' OR '%EX'. " one of the exit buttons in system toolbar
        docking->free( ). " free container and inner controls
        SET SCREEN 0. " to return after the current CALL SCREEN
    ENDCASE.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA: app TYPE REF TO lcl_app.

  CREATE OBJECT app.
  CALL SCREEN 200.

MODULE status_0200 OUTPUT.
  app->pbo( ).
ENDMODULE.

MODULE user_command_0200 INPUT.
  app->pai( ).
ENDMODULE.
```

- Dynpro **0200** of program **ZPRG2**:

  - The layout contains a huge subscreen area named **`SUBAREA`**, and the *OKCODE* element is to be assigned the name **`OKCODE`** (which is mapped to the global variable of ZPRG2 having the same name)
  - The flow logic contains this code:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE status_0200.
  CALL SUBSCREEN subarea INCLUDING 'ZPRG1' '0100'.

PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  CALL SUBSCREEN subarea.
  MODULE user_command_0200.
```

Comment: Very helpful minimal example, much appreciated!